# why this inequality holds? [measure theory]

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

i saw the following inequality and i dont get why this holds.

$$\left\| \partial_{x}^{-1}f \right\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \left\| f \right\|_{L^2(\Omega)} $$

$\text{for } \Omega=(0,1)^2 \text{ and  } \text{ } (\partial_{x}^{-1}f)(x,y)=\int_{0}^{x} f(z,y) dz.$

I tried to apply the Minkowskis inequality after applying the fundamental theorem of calculus but i dont think this makes sense. Any ideas? thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply Holder's (or Cauchy-Schwarz) inequality:
$$| (\partial_x^{-1}f)(x,y)| \le \int_0^x |f(z,y)| \ dz \le x^{1/2} \left( \int_0^1 |f(z,y)|^2 \, dz \right)^{1/2}.$$
Then
$$| (\partial_x^{-1}f)(x,y)|^2 \le x \int_0^1 |f(z,y)|^2 \, dz$$ so that
$$\int_0^1 | (\partial_x^{-1}f)(x,y)|^2  \, dx \le \frac 12 \int_0^1 |f(z,y)|^2 \, dz$$
and
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 | (\partial_x^{-1}f)(x,y)|^2  \, dx \, dy \le \frac 12 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 |f(z,y)|^2 \, dz \, dy$$
which states
$$\|\partial_x^{-1}f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \le \frac 12 \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2.$$

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I dont get the second inequality in the first line, how do you get this?